# Angular one-way binding syntax error

Tags: angularjs

How can I use one-way binding using `ng-bind` in my view? I'm getting `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error` with the following:

```
ng-bind="'Some text here' + (::oneWayBinding) + ' and some more text'"
```

Comment: What version of angular are you using? I think you mean "1 time binding" not one-way.

Comment: I think it is `{{` and not `(`

Comment: @ODelibalta the `{{` notation is not used when binding with the actual ngBind directive. In fact angular processes the `{{}}` in the html to generate a new `<span ng-bind="oneWayBind"></span>`

Comment: I did not even read the directive. My bad...  I assumed it was in a div. Do what Andrew said below and it  should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression must *start* with `::` to be considered a one time binding ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding)). Otherwise it just results in invalid JavaScript when Angular tries to compile it.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.oneTimeBinding = 'FOO';
  
  // change oneTimeBinding property after 2 seconds
  $timeout(function() { $scope.oneTimeBinding = 'NOT FOO'; }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-bind="::'One time binding: ' + oneTimeBinding"></div>
  <div ng-bind="'Not one time binding: ' + oneTimeBinding"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually just got done addressing this issue myself. I was able to solve it using the following.

`ng-bind="::('Some text here' + (oneWayBinding) + ' and some more text')"`

The `::` syntax needs to be outside of everything being bound to the element, not just the angular variable. Ultimately I would recommend breaking it up into something like

`<p>Some text here <span ng-bind="::oneWayBinding"></span> and some more text</p>`

The latter is a sure fire solution for one-way binding. Hope this helps!

Comment: This works, just note that you don't need the outer parenthesis. The `::` is not a JavaScript construct, it's just something that Angular checks for to determine its course of action. That's also why it absolutely must be in the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
<div>Some text here {{::oneWayBinding}} and some more text</div>
```